# Is there a relationship between Arabic ka'b and Greek kybos?

Tags: etymology, greek, arabic

This is a complete layman's question. Online etymology dictionary says about [kaaba](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Kaaba):

> 1734, Caaba, cube-shaped building in the Great Mosque of Mecca, containing the Black Stone, the most sacred site of Islam, from Arabic ka'bah "square house," from **ka'b** "cube."

The etymology of cube is traced to ancient Greek in the same dictionary:

> 1550s, from Middle French cube (13c.) and directly from Latin cubus, from Greek **kybos** "a six-sided die,"

I don't have any training in linguistics. But I know that Greek is an Indo-European language while Arabic is a semitic one and the similarity of the word for cube is striking. Is it just a coincidence, or did one language borrow from the other?

Comment: There's also some similarity between kebab and gyros ;-)

Comment: There seem to be loanwords between Greek, Turkish, and Arabic, see e.g. http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/greek-loanwords-in-arabic.2177718/

Comment: @LubošMotl Those loan words seem to be the result of the Ottoman era. My question involves an exchange (if there is) before 7th century - long before the Turkic influence.

Comment: @layman Welcome to Linguistics SE!

Answer (score 6):

The etymology of Greek *kubos* is unknown, but it is thought to be a loanword. A word like *dice* is of a kind that's easily borrowed, just like the game itself -- compare e.g. *chess* and its similar-sounding equivalents in many languages. So it's plausible, though not provable, that there's a borrowing relationship between the Greek and Arabic words. That said, it's less likely that one language borrowed directly from the other than that they both borrowed the word from some other source: this looks like a [Wanderwort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanderwort).

Answer (score 3):

The translation of the geometrical shape cube into Arabic is mukka'ab. The vast majority of Arabic words come from a three letter simple past tense verb. Mukka'ab comes from the verb [ka'aba] which means 'set heel'. Al-Ka'ba, the Muslims holy srine is derived from that verb to mean 'the heel' of the community or 'fulcrum' where the community gathers and councils meet to discus public matters. It was where the statues of the gods were kept until Muhammed ordered knocking them off on conquering Mecca.
The word mukka'ab to mean cube came later due to the similarity of the shape and the holy shrine. Saying the opposite is like saying that the citrus fruit orange was named after the colour with the same name.
Maybe the similarity between the Arabic and the Greek words is just a coincidence!

Comment: I find no evidence of this, and plenty of counter-evidence (eg the Hebrew cognate).

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: what is "this"?

Comment: @kyle: cp *aurum*, Fr *or* "gold"! Think I'm kidding? It is a wanderword, back to Akkadian at least; Sumerian "gold" reads KU3-SIG17 instead… *orange* is ultimately from Dravidian? Compare Tamil *nārttaṅkāy, narantam* + *kāy*, also Telugu *nāraṅgamu*, Malayalam *nāraṅṅa*, Kannada *nāraṅgi*? What do they say for gold? Tamil: taṅkam, po, kū, kūḻai, urai; the others look like *suvarna* (like satemized *ku* + *ar*). I wont say *narttankay* and *tankam* looked related, because I'm not comfortable with that language. You go ahead tell me they are not! [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orange], [/gold]

Comment: Semi-on-topic: fools gold forms cuboid crystals under certain conditions.

Comment: If there is any semantic link to *ark*, Hebr. *teva* "box, …", consider *kov-* (in Slavic languages), as well as *coffin*, or G *Koffer* (uncertain, Mongol, Tartar cognates) and so on and so forth ... then one really has to wonder. See [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ark]. Some topics here on SE come to mind, about *thalasso*, about the Epic of Atra-Hasis, and, since you mentioned *heel*, the one about *generation* and *knee*. Not questioned yet: Achiles' Heel.

Comment: @vectory I find no evidence that the ordinary meaning of "cube" developed as an analogy from that specific shrine, rather than the other way around.  And that claim would need to explain how the cognate - with its ordinary meaning only - entered Hebrew.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Oh, that's not how I understood it, because it strikes me as unlikely as well, under the assumption that it was indeed cognate to Ancient Greek, etc. I thought Kyle just said the meaning "set heel", "fulcrum of the community" preceeded "cube" for that specific shrine" and I have not really come to understand that. Instead ... I was busy with that ark story, and I'll add that *barca* (see above) can be neatly split into *ba'* and *arka*, if you will. Though Egy *brk* "small boat" (not "ship") seems generally accepted. cp G *Berg* "hill, mointain", *verbergen* "to cover, hide"

Answer (score -10):

Yes there is, the cubes were used in ancient Greece at holly sites long before Arabic came to be - and Arabic is a medieval coiné. Not even a real language. It's a conglomerate like Persian and other Mixtures which somehow became 'languages' and are erroneously being treated as such.

Therefore Ancient Greek **could not** and would not need to borrow such an expression from a language which came out after VII C. AD, or 12 centuries after it became a 'dead language'.  Only the opposite is and can be true.

Comment: It is true that Ancient Greek could not borrow from Arabic, but there's no immediate reason why Arabic could not have borrowed it from Greek (I'm not saying it did, but it's possible). Your comments on Arabic are nonsense. What is "a real language" supposed to be?

Comment: But it did. And that's not all; It  also borrowed an unbelievable amount of medieval English too. To your question: "true language" means a genuine language, not a scrap of phrases from every language you ever come in contact with. Sprachbund is not a language. So this is where we come clear, finally, I believe.

Comment: So you are claiming that Arabic is "a scrap of phrases from every language you ever come in contact with"? That is nonsense. It is true that today Arabic is better described as a family of languages than a language, and that MSA could be described as a Koine (which doesn't prevent it from being a real language). But since Ka'ba has been in use in Arabic for a long time, this is irrelevant to the matter under discussion.

Comment: I see you have edited your answer to state what it did not state before, and so made half of my first comment pointless. It is polite to make it clear when you do that, either by commenting to that effect, or by noting in the answer that it has been edited.

Comment: @ColinFine You are a liar. Twisting my words by attacking the "straw man" to make me look bad is a tactic of the lowest moral and education possible.